# How to display the total number of passed and failed students batch wise

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have a table `tbl_marksObtained` that contains the following data:

```
 stdID          sub       marks_Obtained
 201bct2007   computer      45
 201bct2007   Drawing       0
 202bct2007   computer      0
 203bct2007   Drawing       65
 .
 230bct2007   computer     77
 301bct2008   physics      0
 301bct2008   computer     55
 .
 .
 401bct2009 and so on..
```

Now I would like to display the results as:

```
 year   sub      pass    fail
 2007   computer  20      10
 2007   Drawing   15      15
 2008   computer  28      2
 2009   computer  20      10
```

I obtained the pass fail of particular year and subject by following code:

```
 SELECT 
    SUM( CASE WHEN marks_obtained > '0' THEN 1 END) AS pass,
    SUM( CASE WHEN marks_obtained = '0' THEN 1 END) AS fail  
 FROM   
    tblstudentexammarks 
 WHERE 
    sub ='computer' AND stdID LIKE '%bce2007'
```

but how will I get the above results year wise data

Comment: Group by year? Which seems to be the last four characters of the student id?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 select stdID [Year],sub, 
 sum(case when PF='P' then 1 else 0 end) as Pass,
 sum(case when PF='F' then 1 else 0 end) as Fail
 from(
     select RIGHT(stdID,4) stdID,sub,
     case when marks_Obtained=0 then 'F' else 'P' end PF
     from mark_sheet)a
 WHERE 
 sub ='computer' AND stdID LIKE '%bce2007' 
 group by stdID,sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Joe but stdID column contains other faculty as well and there are data like 203BEX2009,203BEL2009.. and i need the data of only BCT.What to do in that case

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
       RIGHT(stdID,4) as year,
       sub,
       sum(CASE WHEN marks_Obtained>0 then 1 else 0 end) as pass,
       sum(CASE WHEN marks_Obtained=0 then 1 else 0 end) as fail 

from tblstudentexammarks 
group by RIGHT(stdID,4),sub 
order by 1
```